# How to automatically create wrapper for generic classes in autofac

Tags: c#, design-patterns, structure, autofac

I have simple code: 
    public interface ICommand { }

```
public class CommandA : ICommand {}

public class CommandB :ICommand{}

public interface IHandler<in TCommand> where TCommand: ICommand { 
    void Handle(TCommand command); }

public class Handler1: IHandler<CommandA> { public void Handle(CommandA command) {}}

public class Handler2: IHandler<CommandA> { public void Handle(CommandA c) {} }

public class Handler3: IHandler<CommandB> { public void Handle(CommandB c) {} }
public class Handler4: IHandler<CommandB> { public void Handle(CommandB c) {} }
}
```

I register all handlers using AsClosedTypesOf

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(myAssembly).AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IHandler));
```

I have also dispacher class which should find all handler for given command and execute them

```
public class Dispatcher {
void Dispatch<TCommand>(TCommand command) where TCommand : ICommand {
    var handlers = context.Resolve<IEnumerable<IHandler<TCommand>>>();
    foreach (var handler in handlers) { handler.Handle(command); }}}
```

I want to have another dispatcher, kind of wrapper on Handlers like this:

```
public class ActorHandler<TCommand> where TCommand : ICommand {
private IHandler<TCommand> _handler;

public ActorHandler(IHandler<TCommand> handler){
    _handler= handler;}
public void OnReceive(object obj) { var command =(TCommand)obj; _handler.Handle(command);}}
```

How I can do it automatically for all handlers ?

Comment: This seems like a lot of questions wrapped up in a single question. Any single answer will likely help out with one or two points here, but not the whole thing, which will be a frustrating experience for everyone. Given the title is around the dispatcher/wrapper thing (currently point #3), consider removing the other two points from the question and opening separate questions for those.

Comment: Thanks for advise. I removed the first 2 questions.

Comment: Have you read the docs on decorators? http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/adapters-decorators.html#decorators